# Accessing data on the GPU from a dll?

Tags: memory, dll, gpu

Here is the problem: a plugin that modifies vertex coordinates (lots of them) for a 3D application.
All the vertices are already in GPU memory, so it seems pretty wasteful to send another copy over there, do the computation, send the results back to main memory and finally have the host application send them once again to the GPU for update. I do need the computed values back at some point, but the performance concern is fast update of the display. Once the deformation is done, I don't really care how long it takes to get the updated coordinates into main memory.

Is this at all possible?
I've just started learning OpenGL/OpenCL, so I'm not requesting a detailed explanation of the process. Only whether it is doable in a normal fashion, or only through some esoteric hack, or not at all.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using OpenGL and OpenCL. You first need to create the vertex buffer in OpenGL. You can then create an OpenCL context that can share data with the OpenGL one. You can use `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` to get a pointer to the buffer. Obviously there is more to it, google OpenGL OpenCL interop or OpenGL OpenCL shared context for necessary code.

Note: you might have trouble getting the GL context if this is for a closed source and pre-built application.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific (and not post that late). The plugin (dll) hooks to the application through its SDK which doesn't provide access to what it sends to the GPU. Hence my wondering that it might require some hacking.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without the OpenGL handles for context and buffer objects. They hold the memory locations and size for the data. Without them it'd be like searching through RAM for something, you wouldn't know where to start/stop looking, the size, etc. with the added complexity of being on the VRAM. BTW, since you are speaking of .dll's, I assume you are on Windows, there is a chance that the app is using DirectX. It also has OpenCL interop but I've never looked into it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're confirming what I was afraid of. The 3D app has versions for both Windows and Mac and uses OpenGL (and is written in C). For now, I'm only working on Windows. After searching some more in their SDK's sketchy documentation, there is nothing about accessing data on the GPU side. I'll have to come back to it when I know more. Thanks again for your help :)